# is there any helper class spring uses to parse setter's data from xml that I can use?

Tags: java, spring

Using Spring you can put setter/constructor data in bean definition xml like

```
<property name="myList">
   <list>
        <value>value1</value>
   </list>
</property>
```

Now my project has similar requirement I wonder if spring already has well wrapped tool for this so I don't have to reinvent wheel?

thanks

Update:

I use Spring's namespace extension to create my own stuff. so I am responsible for parsing properties.

```
<application:mystuff>
      <property>
         ..............
      </property>
</application:mystuff>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why don't you just use Spring's `ApplicationContext`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `java.beans.XMLDecoder` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/advanced/longpersistence.html